# Compilation and build using make

Tags: ubuntu, make, gcc

Currently when I go invoke make I see the following being executed

```
cc x.c -o x
```

What I would like to see is the following

```
cc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror x.c -l<lib> -lm -o x
```

or maybe

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror x.c -l<lib> -lm -o x
```

Obviously I could type that every time but I'd prefer when I use make to ultimately use cc with those params.

Is there a make config file somewhere?

Comment: What does your `Makefile` contain?

Comment: Erm... where would that be? Or must I create one at the project root? Is there a system wide Makefile?

Comment: Wherever you are when you type `make` and it runs `cc x.c -o x`. (If there is none, that's useful to know too.)

Comment: there is none in that directory anyway - big surprise. Reading up on makefile now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make` generally uses variables for this; in particular:

- `CC` specifies the C compiler to use;
- `CFLAGS` specifies C compiler flags to pass the compiler;
- `LDLIBS` specifies libraries to add (although in general you should really write a `Makefile` which defines everything your program *needs* to build, which typically includes libraries).

So you'd run

```
make CFLAGS="-ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror" LDLIBS="-lm" x
```

to get

```
cc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror x.c -lm -o x
```

and

```
make CC="clang" CFLAGS="-ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror" LDLIBS="-lm" x
```

to get

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror x.c -lm -o x
```

You can also set the variables in your environment (which allows defaults to be set in your shell startup scripts):

```
export CFLAGS="-ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror"
make LDLIBS="-lm" x
```

Given the absence of a `Makefile` in your case, you'll probably find [How does this Makefile makes C program without even specifying a compiler?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/325233/86440) interesting! The [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/) will also come in handy.

Comment: Brilliant! :) that worked

Comment: You're welcome! Be careful if you set defaults though, it can wreak havoc with some builds (so if you download some software, try to build it and it fails, try again without your defaults).

Comment: Good point. While env variables are fine for the moment I intend on putting together my own makefiles. That way I can restrict any changes to where they should be applied. Thanks again.