# -lm doesn't work for my Makefile

Tags: linux, compiling, make

I'm trying to create a Makefile to compile my project. However, when I use the 'math.h' library, my `make` fails. This is the Makefile file :

```
run: tema1
        ./tema1

build: tema1.c
        gcc tema1.c -o tema1 -lm

clean:
        rm *.o tema1
```

The part of the code where I use the pow() and sqrt() is :

```
float score = sqrt(k) + pow(1.25, completed_lines);
```

But, even compiling using '-lm', I still get this error :

```
> /tmp/ccSQVWNy.o: In function `easy_win_score': tema1.c:(.text+0x1518):
> undefined reference to `sqrt' tema1.c:(.text+0x1540): undefined
> reference to `pow' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> <builtin>: recipe for target 'tema1' failed make: *** [tema1] Error 1
```

Any idea why and how can I fix this ? If I only use this in the terminal :

> gcc tema1.c -o tema1 -lm

it works, but in the Makefile, it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your Makefile doesn’t explain how to build `tema1` (from Make’s perspective), so it uses its [built-in rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325235/86440):

- `run` depends on `tema1`;
- `tema1` doesn’t have a definition, but there’s a C file, so Make tries to compile it using its default rule, which doesn’t specify `-lm`.

To fix this, say

```
tema1: tema1.c
        gcc tema1.c -o tema1 -lm
```

instead of `build: tema1.c` etc.

You can reduce repetition by using automatic variables:

```
tema1: tema1.c
        gcc $^ -o $@ -lm
```

To keep “named” rules (`run`, `build` etc.), make them depend on concrete artifacts (apart from `clean`, since it doesn’t produce anything), add separate rules for the concrete artifacts, and mark the “named” rules as phony (so Make won’t expect a corresponding on-disk artifact):

```
build: tema1

tema1: tema1.c
        gcc $^ -o $@ -lm

.PHONY: run build clean
```

It’s also worth changing `clean` so it doesn’t fail when there’s nothing to clean:

```
clean:
        rm -f *.o tema1
```