# My Makefile is empty but make is running some old commands

Tags: make

I had a strange bug that I managed to reduce to the following. I have a folder with only two empty files: a Makefile and a cpp file:

```
$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 erelsgl erelsgl 4096 Mar  3 20:12 .
drwxrwxr-x 13 erelsgl erelsgl 4096 Mar  3 20:10 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 erelsgl erelsgl    0 Mar  3 20:12 Demo.cpp
-rw-rw-r--  1 erelsgl erelsgl    0 Mar  3 20:09 Makefile
$ cat Makefile 
$ cat Demo.cpp
```

When I run `make` I get the expected result:

```
$ make
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

But when I run `make Demo.o` I get a very strange outcome:

```
$ make Demo.o
clang++-5.0 -std=c++17   -c -o Demo.o Demo.cpp
make: clang++-5.0: Command not found
<builtin>: recipe for target 'Demo.o' failed
make: *** [Demo.o] Error 127
```

The command "clang++-5.0 -std=c++17" were actually in the Makefile some days ago, but I have long since then replaced it with clang++-9. And now, as you can see, the Makefile is entirely empty. Why is `make` still running these old commands?

EDIT: The same thing happens when I change the Makefile to contain these two lines:

```
%.o: %.cpp xxx.h
    clang++-9 --compile $< -o $@
```

when the file xxx.h does not exist. This is very confusing: I run `make Demo.o` and it is built with clang++-5.0 instead of clang++-9!

Comment: Do you have a `CXX` and/or `CXXFLAGS` defined in your environment? if so, `make` is likely using those as part of a default rule

Comment: Yes, they are defined! Is there a way to disable this default behavior? (in case I cannot change the environment)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does this Makefile makes C program without even specifying a compiler?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325233/how-does-this-makefile-makes-c-program-without-even-specifying-a-compiler)

Comment: Not sure how portable, but at least with GNU make, `make -r` or `make --no-builtin-rules` should disable builtin rules altogether. However you should always be able to override environment variables at run time ex. `CXX=g++ CXXFLAGS= make Demo.o`

Comment: @steeldriver `-r` is specified by POSIX.

Comment: Why can't you change the environment? `CXX=my-c++ make target`. But you don't even need to: `make CXX=my-c++ target`

Comment: I would recommend breaking the last bit of code into two rules `%.o: %.c\n clang...` and `xyz.o: xxx.h yyy.h ...` (A single line: no recipe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How does this Makefile makes C program without even specifying a compiler?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/325233/86440) for background. Make has built-in rules which tell it how to build various files; in this particular case, since you’re asking for an object file, and there’s a matching `.cpp` file in the current directory, it uses the rule which specifies how to build an object file from a `.cpp` file.

In GNU Make, certain parts of that rule end up using variables; in particular, `CXX` for the C++ compiler, and `CXXFLAGS` for the flags to use when compiling C++ code. If the environment contains values for those variables, those values take precedence over the built-in defaults. Since `CXX` is still set to `clang++-5.0`, Make tries to use that to build `Demo.o`.

With your two-line Makefile, the recipe you define doesn’t get used [because its prerequisites don’t all exist and can’t all be made](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html). Instead, the generic pattern rule gets used again, still with `CXX` set to `clang++-5.0`.

You can disable built-in rules entirely with the `-r` option to `make`. You can also supplement them; thus

```
Demo.o: Demo.cpp xxx.h
```

with no recipe will use the built-in rule, but require `xxx.h` in addition to `Demo.cpp` (and correctly fail since `xxx.h` doesn’t exist and can’t be built).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This issue was very confusing.