# What actually is causing `The System Can not find the file specified` problem in make?

Tags: make

Here is my Simple Makefile:

```
run.exe: link
    gcc link.o -o run

link.o: main.o fun.o
    ld -r main.o fun.o -o link.o

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c -o main.o

fun.o: functionfile.c
    gcc -c functionfile.c -o fun.o

clean:
    del *.o
    del *.exe
```

The question is not really about creating `run.exe` I know several ways to create this. But while I was writing my **Makefile**, I accidently forget to write `.o` after `link` in dependency of `run.exe`( which I know when I found following error after running `make`):

```
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -c functionfile.c -o fun.o
ld -r main.o fun.o -o link.o
cc   link.o   -o link
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc link.o -o link, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'link' failed
make: *** [link] Error 2
```

I guess the file it is saying which it can not find is `link` because it doesn't previously exists and none of Makefile commands create it. My question is if `link` can not be found how the commands of targets 2,3 and 4 runs successfully and able to create respective `.o` files? Why does not it return at the same time when it does not find `link` i.e without executing any of the commands? Help me to sort it if my guess is correct or if it is wrong tell me the actual thing which is happening and problem too!!? And what is this `recipe for target 'link' failed` as I don't have any target named `link`??

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the very first line in your `Makefile`:

```make
run.exe: link
```

This causes Make to try to figure out how to create `link`. It [knows how to build `link` from `link.o`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325235/86440), so it uses the rules provided to create `link.o`, and then tries to create `link` using its built-in rule, which references `cc`. But you don’t have a `cc.exe` command, so it fails — that’s the missing file. All this explains the “<builtin>: recipe for target 'link' failed” error message: Make failed in its attempt to create `link` using a built-in rule.

To fix this, specify the correct prerequisites:

```make
run.exe: link.o
    gcc $^ -o $@
```

This uses automatic variables to avoid repeating information from the rule: `$^` stands for “all the prerequisites” (`link.o`), `$@` stands for “the file name of the target” (`run.exe`).

Comment: so, actually it could not find cc.exe. Can we create it or? And how it knows to make `link` from `link.o`? It means file extention doesn't matter or else??

Comment: File extensions do matter, and that’s what’s wrong with your Makefile. If you fix the extensions as indicated in my answer, you won’t need to create `cc.exe` because Make will stop looking for it. The link in my answer explains why Make “knows” how to build `link` — but its knowledge isn’t great on Windows because it doesn’t know about `.exe` extensions.

Comment: If I named it anything instead of `link` then it does not run even single command? It means same name matters?

Comment: Yes, the names matter. The name before a `:` is the file that is produced, the names after a `:` are the files that are used. You want to build `run.exe` using `link.o`, so the rule needs to be `run.exe: link.o`, and the `gcc` command needs to produce `run.exe`, *i.e.* `gcc link.o -o run.exe` (or `gcc $^ -o $@` using automatic variables).

Comment: Specifying `link` causes commands to run because there’s a `link.o` rule. Make has a built-in rule to build executables with no extension using a `.o` file; in this case that’s `cc link.o -o link`. You’d get the same effect with `main` or `fun`, since there are rules for `main.o` and `fun.o`. Anything else won’t trigger the built-in rule.

Comment: So, as it triggers `cc link.o -o link` it is must to have `cc.exe` as you said in earlier answer? or am i still in misunderstanding? If I am true can we mention anywhere in `makefile` `cc.exe` to avoid the problem?

Comment: It triggers `cc link.o -o link` because the Makefile is wrong. If you fix the Makefile as I indicate in the answer, it won’t trigger `cc link.o -o link` any more and you won’t need `cc.exe`.