# How is this Makefile being encountered?

Tags: make

Here is my simple Makefile:

```
    #create an exe file
    run: link
            gcc link.o -o run
    
    #sketch link.o
    link.o: main.o sum.o
            ld -r main.o sum.o -o link.o
    
    #sketch main.o
    main.o: main.c
            gcc -c main.c -o main.o
    
    #sketch sum.o
    sum.o: sum.c
            gcc -c sum.c -o sum.o
    
    #make clean recipie
    clean:
            rm *.o
            rm run
```

This makefile may be something kind of immature or weak one.But my real concern is all about the process the target are being hit. Before telling actual question, let's first look its output.

```
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -c sum.c -o sum.o
ld -r main.o sum.o -o link.o
cc   link.o   -o link
gcc link.o -o run
```

My question is: is this because of `link` the dependency of `run` or because of `link.o` mention in command section of `run`, `make` command seeks for `link.o` and again it is because of `main.o` `sum.o` the dependencies of `link.o` it looks for mention dependencies or because of `main.o` `sum.o` in command section and then first command in target `main.o` is encountered and `sum.o` and `link.o` respectively? Is it because of file mentioned in dependencies or file mention on the command??

Comment: It is unclear what "this" refers to in your question. Is it the fact that `link` is being built in the second to last step?

Comment: **this** means the last question in my entire post(question).

Comment: What was the `make` command that produced this output?

Comment: It was `make` alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate of your earlier question, [What actually is causing `The System Can not find the file specified` problem in make?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/726282/86440), but let’s use this one to explain in detail what’s going on.

Make takes your Makefile declarations literally:

1. `run: link` tells it that `run` needs `link`, and the associated recipe tells it that to create `run`, it should execute `gcc link.o -o run`
2. `link.o: main.o sum.o` tells it that `link.o` needs `main.o` and `sum.o`, and the associated recipe tells it that to create `link.o`, it should execute `ld -r main.o sum.o -o link.o`
3. `main.o: main.c` tells it that `main.o` needs `main.c`, and the associated recipe tells it that to create `main.o`, it should execute `gcc -c main.c -o main.o`
4. `sum.o: sum.c` does the same for `sum.c` and `sum.o`

When you run

```
make
```

Make tries to satisfy the first target in the Makefile, `run`. It sees that there is no `link` file, and there is no rule in your Makefile which specifies how to build `link`. However [Make “knows” how to build an extensionless file from a `.o` file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325235/86440), so it uses that built-in rule to build `link`; that resolves to

```
cc link.o -o link
```

which is where the `cc` command comes from (strictly speaking, it’s the default value of the `$(CC)` Make variable).

Once `link` is available, Make considers that the prerequisites for `run` are satisfied, and it runs the corresponding recipe:

```
gcc link.o -o run
```

Note that `link` *isn’t actually used* here. It only confuses things; you should write the first rule as

```
run: link.o
```

In detail, Make resolves `run` as follows:

- `run` needs `link`
- `link` has no explicit rule, but can be built using the built-in rule from `link.o`
- `link.o` needs `main.o` and `sum.o`
- `main.o` needs `main.c`, which exists
- `sum.o` needs `sum.c`, which exists

The prequisites are now resolved, and Make can run the recipes:

- `gcc -c main.o -o main.o` to build `main.o`
- `gcc -c sum.c -o sum.o` to build `sum.o`
- `ld -r main.o sum.o -o link.o` to build `link.o`
- `cc link.o -o link` to build `link`
- `gcc link.o -o run` to build `run`

If you rewrite the `run` rule as `run: link.o`, the resolution changes to

- `run` needs `link.o`
- `link.o` needs `main.o` and `sum.o`
- `main.o` needs `main.c`, which exists
- `sum.o` needs `sum.c`, which exists

and the build to

- `gcc -c main.o -o main.o` to build `main.o`
- `gcc -c sum.c -o sum.o` to build `sum.o`
- `ld -r main.o sum.o -o link.o` to build `link.o`
- `gcc link.o -o run` to build `run`

Comment: Thanks a lot....Both post answered...